# sort array by key's value in php

Tags: php

i am new in php , i done't know the array sort. Problem is i need to sort array taht listed bellow to sort by its key key field `order`. means need it sort by '1,2,5'.

Array :

```
Array
(
    [Apple] => Array
        (
            [name] => Apparel & Accessories                 
            [order] => 5
        )

    [Bannana] => Array
        (
            [name] => Business Stationary
            [order] => 1
        )

    [Orenge] => Array
        (
            [name] => Business Cards
            [order] => 2
        )

)
```

How can i sort this array by `Order` ?

nee d to display like ::

```
Array
    (
        [Bannana] => Array
            (
                [name] => Business Stationary                   
                [order] => 1
            )

        [Orenge] => Array
            (
                [name] => Business Cards
                [order] => 2
            )

        [apple] => Array
            (
                [name] => Apparel & Accessories 
                [order] => 5
            )

    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $array = array(
                "Apple" => array(
                        "name" => "Apparel & Accessories",                 
                        "order" => 5
                    ),

                "Bannana" => array(
                        "name" => "Business Stationary",
                        "order" => 1
                    ),

                "Orenge" => array (
                        "name" => "Business Cards",
                        "order" => 2
                    )

            );


    function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
        return $a['order'] - $b['order'];
    }

    usort($array, 'sortByOrder');   


    print_r($array);

?>
```

Output:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Business Stationary
            [order] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Business Cards
            [order] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Apparel & Accessories
            [order] => 5
        )

)
```

Comment: Best answer, nice trick with $a['order'] - $b['order'].

Comment: BTW: I dont know if php smaller / greater is based on difference calculating, but this: return $a['order'] > $b['order']; should work too and this is only a logical operator not mathematical :).

Comment: @JacekKowalewski You are right, have not thought of that. Cool!

Comment: No problem, You can update Your answer if You want, You were first and this is only a really pedantic update ;). Best regards, +1 from me :).

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you to use [`usort()`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_usort.asp). Example:

```
$arr = array
(
    "Apple" => array
    (
        "name" => "Apparel & Accessories" ,
        "order" => 5
    ),

    "Bannana" => array
    (
        "name" => "Business Stationary",
        "order" => 1
    ),

    "Orenge" => array
    (
        "name" => "Business Cards",
        "order" => 2
    )

);


function custom_sort($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['order']==$b['order']) return 0;
    return ($a['order'] < $b['order']) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($arr, "custom_sort");

print '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
print '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Usort function comes here!

```
function sortbyorder($a, $b) {
    if ($a['order'] > $b['order']) return true; 
    else return false;
}
usort ($array, 'sortbyorder');
```

More information here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php
Best regards.

It can also be:

```
function sortbyorder($a, $b) {
    return $a['order'] > $b['order']; 
}
usort ($array, 'sortbyorder');
```

Comment: Thx for upvote, however Rizier123 answer with return $a['order'] - $b['order'] is cleaner :).

Comment: Updated with even cleaner solution :P